# OWIN Hybrid with IdentityServer 3 Authorization code is too long error

Tags: azure, owin, identityserver3, hybrid

Please, help!!!!

I am trying to follow a Hybrid implementation (Azure AD + Identity Server 3) from [here](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples)

I am able to get to the AAD, I seem to get authenticated (get user info, etc) and receive a context.code: [image]

When I pass that code into RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync I get an "**invalid_grant**" and if I look at the client, here is what I see (**Authorization Code is too long**):

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public class Startup
{

    string authority = String.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, aadInstance, tenant);
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = clientId,
            Authority = authority,
            RedirectUri = "https://localhost:44300/",
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = "https://localhost:44300/",
            ResponseType = "code id_token",
            Scope = "openid profile read write offline_access",

            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
                RoleClaimType = "role"
            },

            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = async context =>
                    {
                        string userObjectID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("oid").Value;
                        string tenantID = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("tid").Value;

                        string appBaseUrl = context.Request.Scheme + "://" + context.Request.Host + context.Request.PathBase;
                        context.ProtocolMessage.RedirectUri = appBaseUrl + "/";
                        context.ProtocolMessage.PostLogoutRedirectUri = appBaseUrl;
                        Uri redirectUri = new Uri(context.Request.Uri.GetLeftPart(UriPartial.Path));
                        string authorizationCode = context.Code;



                        // use the code to get the access and refresh token
                        var tokenClient = new TokenClient(
                            Constants.TokenEndpoint,
                            clientId,
                            "secret", AuthenticationStyle.PostValues);

                        var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(
                            authorizationCode, context.RedirectUri);

                        if (tokenResponse.IsError)
                        {
                            throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);
                        }

                        // use the access token to retrieve claims from userinfo
                        var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(
                        new Uri(Constants.UserInfoEndpoint),
                        tokenResponse.AccessToken);

                        var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync();

                        // create new identity
                        var id = new ClaimsIdentity(context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);
                        id.AddClaims(userInfoResponse.GetClaimsIdentity().Claims);

                        id.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken));
                        id.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(tokenResponse.ExpiresIn).ToLocalTime().ToString()));
                        id.AddClaim(new Claim("refresh_token", tokenResponse.RefreshToken));
                        id.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", context.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                        id.AddClaim(new Claim("sid", context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("sid").Value));

                        context.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                            new ClaimsIdentity(id.Claims, context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType, "name", "role"),
                            context.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                    },

                RedirectToIdentityProvider = context =>
                    {
                        // if signing out, add the id_token_hint
                        if (context.ProtocolMessage.RequestType == OpenIdConnectRequestType.LogoutRequest)
                        {
                            var idTokenHint = context.OwinContext.Authentication.User.FindFirst("id_token");

                            if (idTokenHint != null)
                            {
                                context.ProtocolMessage.IdTokenHint = idTokenHint.Value;
                            }

                        }

                        return Task.FromResult(0);
                    }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code in screenshots. They can't be searched or copied and offer poor usability. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.

Comment: The problem is in the "IdentityServer3.Core.Validation.ValidateRequestAsync : line 195" 
https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3/blob/master/source/Core/Validation/TokenRequestValidator.cs
(*same applies for IdSvr4). There is a "non changable" 100 charachters limit. Think this is an oversight/bug.